# Why doesn't the validator like my drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using html/css. The menu looks ok, but the validator tells me :

> Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context

Why is this? And is there another (better) way to do this?
My code looks like this:

```
          <ul id="meny">
            <li>Svenska</li>
                <ul class="undermeny">
                    <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel1">Spel 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel2">Spel 2</a></li>
                    <li>Spel 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Matematik</li>
                <ul class="undermeny">
                    <li>spel 1</li>
                    <li>Spel 2</li>
                    <li>Spel 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Engelska</li>
                <ul class="undermeny">
                    <li>spel 1</li>
                    <li>Spel 2</li>
                    <li>Spel 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>NO</li>
                <ul class="undermeny">
                    <li><a href="om_spelet.html#No_Spel1">Spel 1</a></li>
                    <li>Spel 2</li>
                    <li>Spel 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>SO</li>
                <ul class="undermeny">
                    <li>spel 1</li>
                    <li>Spel 2</li>
                    <li>Spel 3</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you can't have a `ul` as a direct descendant of another `ul`. The solution is to wrap the child `ul` within each `li`.

```
<ul id="meny">
    <li>Svenska
        <ul class="undermeny">
            <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel1">Spel 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel2">Spel 2</a></li>
            <li>Spel 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Matematik
        <ul class="undermeny">
            <li>spel 1</li>
            <li>Spel 2</li>
            <li>Spel 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Engelska
        <ul class="undermeny">
            <li>spel 1</li>
            <li>Spel 2</li>
            <li>Spel 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>NO
        <ul class="undermeny">
            <li><a href="om_spelet.html#No_Spel1">Spel 1</a></li>
            <li>Spel 2</li>
            <li>Spel 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>SO
        <ul class="undermeny">
            <li>spel 1</li>
            <li>Spel 2</li>
            <li>Spel 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only list items may be children of list elements.

Logically, the sublists form part of the "heading" list items. Move them inside.

Meaning, the right syntax should be:

```
<ul id="meny">
  <li>Svenska
      <ul class="undermeny">
          <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel1">Spel 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="om_spelet.html#Spel2">Spel 2</a></li>
          <li>Spel 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  ....
</ul>
```